# change color while animation is playing - adobe edge animate

Tags: jquery, css, animation, adobe, adobe-edge

I have just the question I've mentioned above, nothing really to add <.<. Is it possible to change the color of a element while my animation is playing in adobe edge.

So if I could do something like this:

```
sym.play();
sym.$("slider").css("background-color","red");
```

So this slider is a 'div' inside my symbol and my animation is moving on with a red slider.

Thanks !

Comment: What did you get when you tried?

Comment: I can see the red rectangle for a very short moment and then it gets it color, which I defined in my animation. So I guess my animation is then overdraw the rectangle again.